# Can anyone help me solve this differential Bernoulli equation $2yy' +3 = y^2 + 3x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

it looks like a form of Bernoulli equation. but i just need someone to tell me the substitution that i am going to use. after that i am going to try it out myself

> $$2yy' +3 = y^2 + 3x$$
>   with initial value $y(0) = 8$.

Comment: Please type set your equation with MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Let $u=y^2{}{}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $RHS=u $ then $LHS=\frac {du}{dx} $ hence $\ln|u|=x+c \implies \ln|y^2+3x|=x +c $ now at $x=0,y=8$ so you can get $c $ and get the equation.